# Add "th" to row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I am trying to achieve the below HTML in a Gridview but not getting the results i require

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th element="row">Name</th>
        <td>Data 1 </td>
        <td>Data 2 </td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
<tbody>
```

Im struggling with `<th element="row">Name</th>` area. In my OnRowDataBound (removed some code for clarity) I have the below

```
protected void gv1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TableCellCollection cell = e.Row.Cells;
        cell[0].Attributes.Add("th", "element");
    }
}
```

but this produces the below HTML

```
<td th="element">
```

Other rows seem to be ok.

My inline code is

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
         <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
 ....
```

How could i achieve the required HTML?

Answer (score 0):

`<th>` needs to be defined on an unique `<tr>`, because the `<tr>` means the row.

Example shown here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Thanks but how do i apply this method to a Gridview?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to make the header row `th`

```
protected void gv1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
}
```